# Certain elements go out of place when viewing the website on different screens?

Tags: html, css, position

On my screen everything looks good, but when I look on my computer down stairs, it's just completely out of position. I defined the position with position absolute and then left a certain amount of pixels. How can I keep it centered horizontally and have it against the nav bar vertically at all times.

My screen:

[image]

Screen downstairs:

[image]

```css
.nav-main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
  height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .65;
}
.nav-main .logo {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.nav-main > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-main > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.music {
  background-color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 900px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 524.5px;
  right: 524.5px;
}
.song-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  float: left;
}
.song-2 {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
}
.music h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.music h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main">
  <div class="logo">LogicLucas</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="about.html" class="nav-item">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="content.html" class="nav-item">Content</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="music.html" class="nav-item">Music</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCn63ebEmiYFxhyRVgdCOYtA" class="nav-item">My channel</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="music">
  <h1>Music I used</h1>
  <h3>On this page you can find all the music I used in my skill compilations</h3>
  <div class="song-1">
    <iframe width="350" height="350" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/117698423&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="song-2">
    <iframe width="350" height="350" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/164076894&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your .music class has fixed margins against the screen, try to put them in % so that they will scale at different resolutions.

Comment: I need to change left and right in percentages?

Comment: Yeah, just try for the start something like: left: 30%; right: 30%;

Comment: I have done that one my screen it's centered and on another screen the left side is the same and at the right side it's not center, as seen on my pics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position `.music` relatively and replace the `left` and `right` properties with `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
.music {
  background-color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 900px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.song-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  float: left;
}
.song-2 {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
}
.music h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.music h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="music">
  <h1>Music I used</h1>
  <h3>On this page you can find all the music I used in my skill compilations</h3>
  <div class="song-1">
    <iframe width="350" height="350" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/117698423&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="song-2">
    <iframe width="350" height="350" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/164076894&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thank you! Horizontal it's good know. How do I get the white box against the navigation bar. Pic as it is now: http://imgur.com/lifXh4i

Comment: @LogicLucas - Please post the relevant code for the navigation bar.

Comment: Okay well. It's quite easy. I just add top position of -21px which lines it up with the nav bar! Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @LogicLucas - You're Welcome. Adding `margin-top` is one way to do it but I was tracing where it was coming from.